# Display Alternate Rows of table in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I have two objects containing two tables with same column name.
I need to display these table values in mail body using script tak in ssis.
The mail should contain ,first row of table one and below it should the row of second table.

The query written below only displays single table values.

```
oleDA.Fill(Obj_Duration, Dts.Variables["User::Obj_Duration"].Value);
        foreach (DataColumn col in Obj_Duration.Columns)
        {
            Mail = Mail + "<th bgcolor='#7A378B' align='center'><font color='#FFFFFF'>" + col.ColumnName + "</font></th>";
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in Obj_Duration.Rows )
        {



            sMail = sMail + "<tr>";

            foreach (DataColumn col in Obj_Duration.Columns)
            {


                sMail = sMail + "<td align = 'center'>" + row[col.Ordinal].ToString() + "</td>";
            }

            sMail = sMail + "</tr>";
            Mail = Mail + sMail;
            sMail = "";
            Mail = Mail + "<br>";
        }

        sMail = "";
        Mail = Mail + "</table>";
        Mail = Mail + "<br>";
```

Need to change this query.

Comment: @Marc -Help required.

Answer (score 0):

Walk first table as foreeach loop and the second table just use the indexed position of the first tables row to test and see if a row exists and retrieve the information from it rather than trying to walk that one as a for each loop

So inside your first loop at the end just add something like:

```
            int i = Obj_Duration.Rows.IndexOf(row);
            if (AlternatingDataTableName.Rows.Count - 1 >= i)
            {
                DataRow alternatingRow = AlternatingDataTableName.Rows[i];
                   //Start TR

                foreach (DataColumn col in AlternatingDataTableName.Columns )
                {
                    //Start TD
                     //alternatingRow[col.Ordinal].ToString()
                    //End TD
                }

                // end TR
            }
```

just build the string how you want I put in some comments to hint what you might want to do when.  And change the name of the datatable variable to your second Table variable.  To make sure you know where I am suggesting this goes your whole code would look something like:

```
        oleDA.Fill(Obj_Duration, Dts.Variables["User::Obj_Duration"].Value);
        foreach (DataColumn col in Obj_Duration.Columns)
        {
            Mail = Mail + "<th bgcolor='#7A378B' align='center'><font color='#FFFFFF'>" + col.ColumnName + "</font></th>";
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in Obj_Duration.Rows )
        {



            sMail = sMail + "<tr>";

            foreach (DataColumn col in Obj_Duration.Columns)
            {


                sMail = sMail + "<td align = 'center'>" + row[col.Ordinal].ToString() + "</td>";
            }

            sMail = sMail + "</tr>";
            Mail = Mail + sMail;
            sMail = "";
            Mail = Mail + "<br>";

            int i = Obj_Duration.Rows.IndexOf(row);
            if (AlternatingDataTableName.Rows.Count - 1 >= i)
            {
                DataRow alternatingRow = AlternatingDataTableName.Rows[i];
                   //Start TR

                foreach (DataColumn col in AlternatingDataTableName.Columns )
                {
                    //Start TD
                     //alternatingRow[col.Ordinal].ToString()
                    //End TD
                }

                // end TR
            }


        }

        sMail = "";
        Mail = Mail + "</table>";
        Mail = Mail + "<br>";
    }
```